# difficulties in setting an AVD android

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have difficulties setting an AVD in Eclipse Indigo Java EE IDE.
I tried many skins with many APIs but I couldn't get the correct AVD  I see often in tutorials besides, the control buttons and the keyboard don't show up in my AVD. Even the settings window is different, here it is:
[AVD settings](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/16/avdu.png/)

and here is the AVD I got usually:
[AVD running](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/254/avd2.png/)

may anyone help me out, and tell me the exact specifications to choose in setting my AVD plz!!!

Comment: Did you try turning off the hardware keyboard setting?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check the 2 checkboxes saying Hardware keyboard present and display a skin with hardware controls.By doing this you'll get keyboard and other controls on your AVD.